# Sort code in Prolog

Tags: sorting, syntax, prolog

I'm writing a program in prolog and need some help.  This could probably be considered a homework question.

I have two sort algorithms written and working.  My goal is to pass in a list, and if it is greateror equal to than length 5, use sort method 1.  if it's less than 5, use sort method 2.    The sort methods both return a sorted list, and the main method that they are used in should return the sorted list.

here's the main method that I'm working with:

```
%Main method to run program
main(List, Result) :-
size(List, N),
(   N => 5;
    sort1(List, X),
sort2(List, X)).
```

Every time I try to run this, though, I get an error:

?- main([1,5,1,4,2,6,1]).
ERROR: Undefined procedure: main/1
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         main/2
false.

I'm not sure what this error means.  Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The error message is quite obvious. You've defined `main/2` but call with one argument. Also, "greater or equal" is spelled `>=` in Prolog, not `=>`.

Comment: Alright...I've switched the >= to =>, and changed the method to be:
mainInsert(List, Result) :-
 size(List, N),
 (   N <= 15;
     sort1(List, X),
 sort2(List, X))
 Result = X.
So here it uses both parameters which are passed in.  But now I have an error that says: Syntax error: Operator expected
and another error that says: ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: mainInsert/2 (DWIM could not correct goal).  I'm not sure what these mean either.

Answer (score 2):

You must correct the syntax. From your description:

```
main(List, Result) :-
    length(List, N),
    (   N >= 5
    ->  sort1(List, Result)
    ;   sort2(List, Result)
    ).
```

Comment: Alright, I've reformatted it and it now works correctly, except it is not outputting the correctly sorted list.  I now have this as my method, which causes an error.

main(List, Result) :-
 length(List, N),
 (   N >= 5
     ->  sort1(List, X),
 Result is X
 ;   Result is sort2(List, X),
 Result is X
 ).

It causes this error when run: ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `sort2/2' is not a function
^  Exception: (8) _G225 is sort2([1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 1], _G314) ? creep
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *is* it's the arithmetic evaluation builtin, you can't use in this context. In the answer you can see the exact syntax required. Did you defined sort1/2 and sort2/2 ?

Comment: Yes, both sort1/2 and sort2/2 are defined.

In the case that I can't use is, can I use = instead of is?

Like, Result = sort1(List, Result),?

Comment: no, in Prolog we have *relations*, not functions, i.e. *Result* in relation *sort2* with *List*. sort2 will *succeed* or *fail* depending on the fact that such relation holds.

Comment: Oh, ok.  that makes a bit more sense.  so what should I be aiming to do in order to have it return the sorted list?  I'm under the impression that X in the sort methods is the returned sorted list, so shall I do something to that variable?

Comment: As I wrote it, *Result* is 'returned' to caller (it appears as argument in the head). You could write `sort2(List, X), X = Result`, but it's useless.

Comment: Alright, I got it and it works now.  thanks so much for your help